# How to concatenate several characters into a single string and store it in a string variable?

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

I am currently working on an assignment where I take a command line argument (an integer value) from the user and a string. The code takes every element of the string (for example, 'H' from 'Hello') and encrypts it using the key. So if the user input the command line argument as 3, H would jump 3 places to K and so on.

I'm doing this by using array and a for-loop, i.e as the loop counter increases, the code checks the corresponding array element ('H' would be array[0]) and encrypts it back together. But how do I concatenate the the encrypted characters into a single string and store it in a single variable so that I can print it outside the  for-loop once the appending is complete.

In i=0, for key 3, H would be K, but then in the next loop, as 'e' becomes 'h', it should go and attach itself to 'K' to make 'Kh', then 'Kho', then 'Khoo' and finally 'Khoor', and then outside the for loop (since the loop has exited), I want to be able to print it out in one go.

I'm a beginner in C so please pardon if I've made any terminological errors or this sounds too confusing. I would appreciate your help.

For more context, this is a minimally reproducible code as someone suggested.

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n;  i++){
    char D = plaintext[i];
    printf("%c", D);
    }
```

This is the basics of the code without the encryption part. As you can see, the entire input will print itself, but only every time the loop, well, loops. I want to modify the code so that it doesn't immediately print D, but that D's character, which changes with every loop, keeps concatenating onto itself in another variable, so that when the loop exits, I can print out the entire string variable at once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have added it, thank you. Tell me if it's workable.

Comment: In C a "string" is a character array (or allocated block of memory) where the next character after the last character of the string is the *nul-terminating* character `'\0'` (equivalent to plain old `0`). That is how functions that operate on a string know where the end is. So for the string `"Hi"`, you need 3 characters of storage for `'H', 'i', '\0'`. So your `for` loop need only be `for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++)` -- when you reach the *nul-terminating* character `input[i]` tests `0/false` and the loop exits. To replace a character with the encrypted one, just overwrite that character.

Comment: @Raunak You may change the command line argument in place. There is no need to create an intermediate array.

Comment: You need to include `ctype.h` for `isalpha()`, `isupper()` and `islower()`. Your loop could be `for (int i =  0; input[i]; i++) { if (isalpha(input[i]) { input[i] = (input[i] + shift - isupper(input[i]) ? 'A' : 'a')  % 26 + isupper(input[i]) ? 'A' : 'a'; } putchar (input[i]); } putchar ('\n');` See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand how the addition works. Note: if your character `'y'` and your `shift` is `3` then your character wraps to `'z', 'a', 'b'`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The problem has been solved but I'd still like to know what you mean. By command line argument, are you referring to main's argument (argv)? It's already set to accept integer inputs only. Please clarify further,

Comment: @Raunak You wrote in the question: "I take a command line argument (an integer value) from the user and a string." So change the string in place in the command line argument.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, however I already have the actual encryption part pretty much laid out (and it's very similar to yours).

Comment: Good deal. You can separate the *ternary* and just encode for upper and lower case as `message[i] = (message[i] + shift - 'A') % 26 + 'A';  /*encrypt uppercase */ ` or for lowercase `message[i] = (message[i] + shift - 'a') % 26 + 'a';` Do try the loop using `for (i = 0; input[i]; i++)` and use the *nul-terminating* character to signify end of string. No need to compute the length. [CS50 Encypher Example](https://paste.opensuse.org/48144372)  (oops comment for lowercase should be `/* if a-z, encrypt lowercase */`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the assignment is. But you can set a strings length to whatever you want and assign by index like this:

```
int n = strlen(input);
// VLA use with caution.
char s[n];

for (int i = 0, i < n, i++)
{
    char D = plaintext[i];
    // do whatever
    printf("%c", D);
    s[i] = D;
    // add to string
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've added a reproduction of the basic code in the OP if that helps further. I'll try to see if this works.

Comment: Also I am assuming that the ) after %s is a typo?

Comment: Yes thats a typo.